# Sqlite query to check if field exist fails

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using the following query to check if a specific urn is present (yes or no) and I am getting a yes (which is incorrect since the urn is not in the table)

```
sqlstr = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM main.mytable WHERE `urn` = 'dssdsdds')";
        char **results = NULL;
        int rows, columns;
        sqlite3_get_table(db, sqlstr, &results, &rows, &columns, &error);
if(rows >0 )
{
///Item is present
}
```

I know the urn is not present however i am still getting rows > 0 (rows = 1) Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The `SELECT EXIST` will always return with something, it will either be "true" or "false".

A better solution (in my opinion) might be to use e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main.mytable WHERE `urn` = 'dssdsdds'
```

Then fetch the single row and check its single column value. If it's zero the "urn" doesn't exist.

---

And a general tip when it comes to database queries: Connect to the database *and perform the query*. That way you will see what the query actually returns.

Comment: I tried the above `sqlite3_get_table(db, sqlstr, &results, &rows, &columns, &error);` but that always returns false (rows ==0)